# LSI 2208 9286-8e MegaRAID controller beeping when connected to 24-bay NexentaSTOR JBOD enclosure

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, raid, hardware-raid, lsi, battery

I am getting beeping from the LSI external RAID controller even if I properly shutdown and there is no array re-initialization.

Would I be required to use a battery back (BBU) with the LSI controller if it's driving an external enclosure with an expander chip?

Details: firmware and drivers are all 5.5 for Windows

[Sans Digital NexentaStor](http://www.sansdigital.com/nexenta-series/nx424x6r.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that installing a battery pack helps with scenarios where an extender chip is used (for internal connections, LSI strongly recommends it).  In my scenario, expander chip resides inside NexentaStor enclosure -- creating a similar runtime environment.

Comment: I just ran into something similar with an HP controller and an internal expander backplane. The cache module failed and the drives went offline because the expander requires controller cache. Grrr.